# How to add header comments to webpack uglified JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, minify, uglifyjs

I am currently using the following webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: "index.js"
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        query: {
          presets: ['latest']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true}) ]
}
```

This works exactly how I want it to. But now I want to add some comments with project info to the output file, on top of the one line with uglified code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the comments to the code after minification using Webpack's [BannerPlugin()](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/#root):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
new webpack.BannerPlugin(banner);
// or
new webpack.BannerPlugin(options);
```